# Vuetify: Table rows of checkboxes

Tags: checkbox, html-table, row, vuetify.js

I'm using vuetify and trying to use either a data-table, or simple table to display rows of checkboxes and a couple of text fields.

Like this:
[image: Using plain html]

However, when I use `v-simple-table` all of the checkboxes and fields have their own lines; breaking the table.
[image: Using v-simple-table]

```html
<v-form>
 <h3>Shifts:</h3>
 <v-simple-table>
  <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>Su</th><th>M</th><th>T</th><th>W</th><th>Th</th><th>F</th><th>Sa</th><th>From:</th><th>To:</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td>
    <v-checkbox></v-checkbox>
   </td>
   <td>
    <v-checkbox></v-checkbox>
   </td>
   <td>
    <v-checkbox></v-checkbox>
   </td>
   <td>
    <v-checkbox></v-checkbox>
   </td>
   <td>
    <v-checkbox></v-checkbox>
   </td>
   <td>
    <v-checkbox></v-checkbox>
   </td>
   <td>
    <v-checkbox></v-checkbox>
   </td>
   <td>
    <v-text-field value="9:00"></v-text-field>
   </td>
   <td>
    <v-text-field value="22:00"></v-text-field>
   </td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
 </v-simple-table>
</v-form>
```

Changing `v-simple-table` to just `table` gives me the correct layout.

I wouldn't mind using a data-table, but I didn't see a way to have a row of checkboxes instead of a row of data text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The v-simple-table component is a simple wrapper component around the
>    element. Inside the component you can use all the regular
>   table elements such as `<thead>`, `<tbody>`, `<tr>`, etc.

v-simple table give you some extra options which you don't have to program like fixed headers, or a dense format.

So when you use v-simple-table u still have to define table

Comment: Changing the code to `<v-simple-table><table>....</table></v-simple-table>` did indeed fix the issue. This seems like a bug to me though. None of the [examples](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/simple-tables) show a written `<table>` element within the `<v-simple-table>` element. Thanks for the help!